# Move the PR2 arm through some predefined points

Tags: ros, joint-trajectory-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner with ROS. I am doing a simple task of writing a controller to move the PR2 arm through some predefined points. So, I need the values of [r_shoulder_pan_joint, r_shoulder_lift_joint, r_upper_arm_roll_joint, r_elbow_flex_joint, r_forearm_roll_joint, r_wrist_flex_joint, r_wrist_roll_joint] and similarly for the left arm, for each of these points. I move the PR2 arm through these points using the interactive manipulation, and am trying to listen to a topic to get these joint values. But I don't know what topic publishes these joint values. What topic should I subscribe to for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35747/move-the-pr2-arm-through-some-predefined-points/) by [Mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/2162/mayank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC: /joint_states

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1